# avoid select with subselect

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with people and language this person knows. For ex

```
Name    Language

John    Engl ish
Bill    English
John    German
Bill    Japanese
Li      Chinese
```

I want to select all people knowing English and German languages.
The simple way is to do it:

```
select name from persons p where 
exists (select 1 
        from persons pp 
        where pp.name=p.name 
        and pp.language="English")
AND
exists (select 1 from persons pp 
        where pp.name=p.name 
        and pp.language="English")
```

Complexity of request is n^2;
But, what if I need to select all persons knowing English, German and Russian? I'll have complexity n^3. And so on..
Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: With your current table, the answer by @rid is a good solution, but in practice, you should probably have 3 tables, one with persons, one with languages and one junction table that tells you which person speaks which language. I'm curious what you're going to do in your current table when you have two people named John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the names of people that speak both English `and` Japanese; not the name of people that either English `or` Japanese, correct?  If so, here's a way of doing it without any joins or subqueries:

```
select name, count(name)
from persons
where language in ('English', 'Japanese')
group by name
having count(name)=2
```

If you need to add more languages, just add the additional languages to the `where` clause, and increase the number in the last line to the number of languages that you have.

Comment: This assumes that the table above includes only unique records.  As long as no one can include (Bill,English) (Bill,English) more than once, this works well.

Comment: @AldenW. is right. How about
 select name, count(distinct(language)) as c
from persons
where language in ("English", "German")
group by name
having c=2

Comment: yes, good point Alden.  There should be a unique constraint on the table, on the fields (name, language), to prevent duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name from persons p where p.language in ('English', 'German', 'Russian');
```

Comment: this will return people who knows only English or only German but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one select

```
Select name from (
    Select name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT language
              ORDER BY language ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as gr from persons group by name) as t
WHERE gr = 'English Russian';
```

But this one will work for exact matches. You can use  INSTR mysql function for searching in more languages.

However, my main advice is to create another structue because you have got many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 0):

Revise Table Structure to:

**people**

```
person_id | name
----------+------
1         | John
2         | Bill
3         | Li
```

**languages**

```
language_id | language
------------+---------
1           | English
2           | German
3           | Japanese
4           | Chinese
```

**people_have_languages**

```
person_id | language_id
----------+------------
1         | 1
2         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 3
3         | 4
```

Now you that you would have a normalized table structure, here would be your query:

```
SELECT
  `people`.`name`
FROM
  `people`
  INNER JOIN `people_have_languages` ON (`people`.`person_id`=`people_have_languages`.`person_id`)
  INNER JOIN `languages` ON (`people_have_languages`.`language_id`=`languages`.`language`)
WHERE
  `language` IN ('English', 'German', 'Russian')
GROUP BY
  `people`.`person_id`
```